# Algorithm for distributing workload in a thread pool

Tags: multithreading, algorithm

Let's imagine that we have *T* number of threads and we want to distribute a problem of size *N* to those threads. Every thread will chose a part of that problem to execute it. Each thread will use the thread_id (a number from 0 to T-1), the T and the N in order to calculate the range of the sub-problem. Let's say that the range of the sub-problem is [S, E) where S and E belong to [0, N].

For example. Let's say we have an array of integers. The size of the array is 10. We want increase each element of that array by one and we want to do that in parallel using 4 threads.

- The 1st thread with thread_id==0 will use range [0, 3)
- The 2nd thread with thread_id==1 will use range [3, 6)
- The 3rd thread with thread_id==2 will use range [6, 8)
- The 4th thread with thread_id==3 will use range [8, 10)

Does anyone know a fast algorithm that will calculate those ranges? Preferably without atomics or branches.

Comment: Realistically, creating a thread is a thousand times slower than any reasonable way you could possibly calculate those ranges.  Don't worry about it.

Comment: @MooingDuck Could you elaborate? Did I misread the question or am I missing something? The op doesn't ask for a scheduling, just a division of the range.

Comment: Also how picky are you about those exact ranges?  Is it alright if a different thread has the slightly smaller range instead of always the last one?

Comment: @ciamej: My point was that if I use an absurdly slow algorithm to calculate the ranges, it will make no measurable difference to the performance of the overall code, making the entire question pointless.   Kind of like "Hey, I'm moving everything I own from house A to house B; Should I leave my alarm clock behind to save on weight?"

Comment: @Pan. Christopouls Charit: Does it matter if for your example you get a different range, but still a fair one - like [0,2), [2,5), [5,7), [7,10)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're looking for such an equation?

```
S = floor(thread_id * N/T)
E = floor((thread_id + 1) * N/T)
```

If you multiply first (`threadId * N`) and divide later (`/N`) you can use integers for the computations and `floor` function is not necessary.

Comment: It would already break at the example. You would get (0,2), (2,5) ... Maybe it's sufficient though.

Comment: @luk32 it would produce [0,2), [2,4), [4,7), [7,10). How is it different from the op's proposed sequence?

Comment: 1st. `(1+1)*10/4` is 5 to me, so it would be (2,5). 2nd. You really ask, how is  (0,2) different from (0,3)? I am not saying it matters, I am saying it is different. I said, that maybe this distribution is sufficient.

Comment: @luk32 The op just aksed for a fair division of the range. Of course [0,2) is different than [0,3), but that difference is of no importance. Why did you write that my solution 'breaks'? I think it's completely valid.

Comment: It breaks because OP gave expected output, and your method provides different. "*The 1st thread with thread_id==0 will use range [0, 3)*". For the last time, I am saying it might not matter =), and probably does not matter. I just said, it is different from given expectation. Nothing more.

Comment: @luk32 Come on ;) The output is just an example. Not a specification.

Comment: This algorithm seems quite efficient with fair distribution! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think these two examples should work. All operations are integer. Except the one marked that it's not.

This one has simpler logic, however it does not distribute work as you require. It would assign the bigger chunk of work to all workers except the last one which would get significantly lower share. It shouldn't be a problem in theory as the maximal amount of work for one worker stays the same.

```
items_per_thread = ceil(N/T); // This is not an integer division.
start = thread_id*items_per_thread;
stop = min(start+items_per_thread, N);
```

This one should distribute work as you require.

```
items_per_thread = N/T;
start = thread_id*items_per_thread+min(thread_num, N mod T);
stop = start+items_per_thread;
if(thread_num < N mod T) stop += 1;
```

I don't think it's possible to avoid branches.

Feeling adventurous I made a [live demo](http://ideone.com/2cQggf) in python, it includes ciamej's method too.:

```
import math
def distribution1(id ,N, T):
    items_per_thread = math.ceil(N/T);
    start = id*items_per_thread;
    stop = min(start+items_per_thread, N);
    return (start, stop)

def distribution2(id ,N, T):
    items_per_thread = math.floor(N/T);
    start = id*items_per_thread+min(id, N % T);
    stop = start+items_per_thread;
    if(id < N % T): stop += 1;
    return (start, stop)

def distribution3(id ,N, T):
    S = math.floor(id * N/T)
    E = math.floor((id + 1) * N/T)
    return (S,E)

def distribute(N, T, method):
    ret = []
    for i in range(T):
        ret.append(method(i, N, T))
    return ret

N=10
T=4
print(distribute(N, T, distribution1))
print(distribute(N, T, distribution2))
print(distribute(N, T, distribution3))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 3), (3, 6), (6, 9), (9, 10)]
[(0, 3), (3, 6), (6, 8), (8, 10)]
[(0, 2), (2, 5), (5, 7), (7, 10)]
```

Comment: `double items_per_thread = double(N)/T; int start = int(thread_id*items_per_thread); int stop = int((thread_id+1)*items_per_thread)-1;` Use of double avoids the branches

Comment: I assumed everything is an integer.

Comment: Just because all inputs and outputs are integers doesn't mean the intermediate values must be.  Note my casting both to and from `double`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the edited version of the comment, and assumed you wanted to correct type. Not provide alternative. Of course you're right. Although the solution is not ok. For thread 0, stop is`int((0+1)*2,5)-1 = 2-1 = 1`. MY fast python implementaion gave such a sequence: `[(0, 1), (2, 4), (5, 6), (7, 9)]`

Comment: Mine produces `(0,1)(2,4)(5,6)(7,9)`, not sure why you think that's not OK.  Oh!  Mine uses inclusive bounds rather than exclusive, that's probably the source of confusion.  Simply remove the `-1` at the end to get exclusive bounds: `(0,2)(2,5)(5,7)(7,10)`.  Then again, your comment there is inclusive bounds, but the code in the answer is exclusive...